# Angular spinner infinite looping while ngIf in router-outlet

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, subscribe, subject

I am creating an application with frontend in Angular with backend in Laravel.

This application includes an interceptor to display a spinner. For this, I created a service with a BehaviorSubject and an Observable like this:

```
export class SpinnerService {

  private loadingSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
  public loading: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(
  ) {
    this.loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>( false );
    this.loading = this.loadingSubject.asObservable();
  }
  changeLoadingStatus(status: boolean) {
    this.loadingSubject.next( status );
  }
}
```

In component I do a subscribe in this Observable and pass the value to loading variable like this:

```
this.sSpinner.loading
      .pipe(delay(0)) 
      .subscribe((loading) => {
        this.loading = loading;
        console.log(loading);
      });
```

I put a mat-spinner next to the router-outlet and includes the *ngIf directive, like this:

```
<mat-card class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="loading" class="loading-container flex-content-center"> </mat-spinner>
    <router-outlet> </router-outlet>
</mat-card>
```

That way it works, but the route-outlet and the spinner are displayed.
If I place the *ngIf directive on the router-outlet with the inverse loading parameter, to hide router-outlet, like this:

```
<mat-card class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="loading" class="loading-container flex-content-center"> </mat-spinner>
    <router-outlet *ngIf=" ! loading"> </router-outlet>
</mat-card>
```

The app enters an infinite loop, reloading the page until the memory overflows.

I understand that I can, through css, stylize and make the appearance beautiful without using *ngIf in the router-outlet, however, I would like to understand the reason why the app enters infinite looping in this case.

Any help will be welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Quick sanity check, please include the code where you are assigning the value to loading. If it is indeed an observable and not just a Boolean you’ll need to include and async pipe in the *ngIf

Comment: bilasc01 thank you for fast answer.. I add the subscribe code. The value return in subscribe is boolean, I can see in console.log. Any sugestion?

Comment: Could you please add the code for the service in your question?

Comment: Pankaj thanks for reply.. I add code of the service. In Interceptor I only call the function changeLoadingStatus in the SpinnerService in initial with true and in finalize with false.

Comment: What triggers the call to `changeLoadingStatus`?  As I understand it, the presence of the router outlet will affect what routes are injected into the component (as it changes whether it is delegating to a child component or not), so guarding a router-outlet with `ngIf` might lead to some wonky behavior if you were say calling `changeLoadingStatus` as a consequence of the route changing.

Comment: Mark thanks for your reply. The interceptor trigger the changeLoadingStatus. When I start a HTTP request I call it and pass true in parameter, after complete request I call again passing false. I have a component dashboard and router-outlet is there, all routes is rendering there, only login is rendering out there. So when I navigate to a route, the component is charged and the request is done, after the return of the first request the component starts looping. Any sugestion?

Comment: Why don't you use `[hidden]="loading"` attribute instead in the `router-outlet`?

Comment: Shuvo thanks for suggestion.. But I try it and router-outlet dont hide with this directive

Comment: @MichelSilva: And what causes the HTTP request to load?  The child component?  In which case the child component would be destroyed (due to router-outlet being removed) as soon as the HTTP request starts?  It would be nice to get a complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: As far as suggestions go, there are a number of things that might work.  I find the cleanest is to use content projection instead of route inheritance for the loading component.  i.e. push the spinner component to be a member of each page, and use ngIf on that page's content instead.  Rather than hiding the router outlet.  It would be easy to express as a template called say `<app-standard-page>` that includes your spinner component and an `<ng-content>` that is guarded on the loaded state.  Then your child pages all have `<app-standard-page><div>Page content</div></app-standard-page>`

Comment: Mark, yes. The child component load the requests to route on ngInit. I dont understant third question. I will reproduce the complete exemple to you see.

Comment: @MichelSilva: Right so presumably you have some kind of causal chain like this: Child component init > HTTP requests started > Spinner Service Loading > Parent Component Notified > Router Outlet removed > Child component destroy > HTTP requests cancelled > Spinner Service Not Loading > Parent Component Notified > Router Outlet added > Child component init > ad infinitum

Comment: Mark.. You are right. Its occurs becouse my child component is destroied and recried, so its make a infinite looping. Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 3):

I realy want to know what occurs in this case, why reload occur when I put ngIf directive in the router-outlet. But by hour I use css to hide:

```
<mat-card class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
  <mat-spinner *ngIf="loading" class="loading-container flex-content-center"></mat-spinner>

  <div [style.display]="loading ? 'none' : 'block'">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem too.
Finaly used this
main-layout html :

```
<div class="row main-body custom-scrollbar">
    <div [style.display]="showSpinner==true ? 'none' : 'block'" class="col-12 my-4 px-4">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

main-layout ts :

```
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs';
showSpinner = true;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.spinnerService.requestCount$.pipe(debounceTime(1)).subscribe(count => {
            if (count > 0) {
              this.showSpinner = true;
              this.spinnerService.show();
            }
            else {
              this.showSpinner = false;
              this.spinnerService.hide();
            }
          });
      }
```